# How do you translate array items and join them?

Tags: twig

Using twig, how can I translate all items in an array and join them with a slash?
Do I have to use an additional variable or is there a cleverer method?

For the moment, I'm doing something like this:

```
{% set labels = [] %}
{% for feature in menu_item.features %}
  {% set labels = labels|merge([feature|trans([], 'features')]) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ labels | join(' / ')}}
```

It sucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just output the content while you're looping ?

```
{% for feature in menu_item.features %}
  {% if loop.index0 > 0 %}/{% endif %}
  {{feature|trans}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't like this method because of the special case, but I must admit it is simpler than my solution... accepted.

Comment: I think that "if loop.index0 > 0" could be shortened to just "if loop.index0"

Comment: maybe because sometimes we want to have separator for each item

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm late to the party, but you can now do this easily with the map filter:

```
{{ menu_item.features|map(feature => feature|trans)|join(' / ') }}
```

See documentation:

- Twig >v1.41: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/map.html
- Twig >v2.10: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/map.html
- Twig v3.x: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html

Comment: you are the champion! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not everything should be done within the "view".

This type of code is probably much better placed within your controller logic and then passed into the view as the merged+joined result. Because in your example all you're doing is compiling a result which can much more easily be done within code.